# Sorting using tablesorter issue for french language

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tablesorter

I am using [TableSorter 2.9.1](http://tablesorter.com/docs/), my issue is text is not sorting correctly for french language, like **É** in asp Gridview. Does anyone have solution?

Comment: plez show your effort.........

Comment: @ShujaatAbdi Please speak plain old english ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own custom parser, as shown [here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html)

It also shows [here](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-locale-sort.html) how to work with accent characters, which is better suited.

Answer (score 1):

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Example: Sorting non-ASCII characters

For sorting strings with non-ASCII characters, i.e. strings with accented characters (e, é, è, a, ä, etc.), strings from languages other than English: use String.localeCompare. This function can compare those characters so they appear in the right order.

```
var items = ['réservé', 'premier', 'cliché', 'communiqué', 'café', 'adieu'];
items.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});
```

// items is ['adieu', 'café', 'cliché', 'communiqué', 'premier', 'réservé']

Answer (score 0):

You should sort using a "latinised" version of the text to perform the sort.

This might help, not only for french diacritics : [latinise](http://semplicewebsites.com/removing-accents-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're using v2.9.1, I'll assume you're using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/). Try out the [`sortLocalCompare` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortlocalecompare) which replaces accented characters automatically with their equivalents.